# Distance between segment and ellipse

Tags: c#, optimization, graph-algorithm, computational-geometry

I'm trying to find an efficient method to calculate the distance between a given segment and an ellipse:

Studying a bit I found that link on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJNS9RLmixw) and tried to replicate the method using familiar C# functions.
I had to add some extensions for certain calculations, like finding an intersection between ellipse and segments/line (ellipses with rotation).
After a few hours, I have managed to replicate the method, but apparently it does not seem too efficient. or maybe yes, I don't know.

I will illustrate it in colors instead of using the traditional nomenclature because I did not have time to put the letters on the chart.

[image]

the magenta segment perpendicular to the initial segment is calculated using the distance from the first intersection between the auxiliary segment (Blue) and the circle (Red)

Comment: I think simplest method is to calculate distance the line and the line connecting the centers of the elipse (see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_between_two_straight_lines).  Then subtract the formula of the elipse.

Comment: Find the distance between the line L containing the segment s, and the ellipse. This is calculus. If that min distance is realized on s, you are finished. If the min distance is realized off s, then the min is one or the other endpoint of s.

Comment: "apparently it does not seem too efficient": what do you mean ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I mean that the method derives from the graphical method in the YouTube link above, although it is not a graphical method since I have used double-precision calculation, and they are not too many calculations, it is an indirect method, finding an intersection to find a tangent. Sometimes the tangent doesn't really touch the ellipse, I have the approximate distance but I think with this method I won't be able to find the point of intersection between the tangent and the ellipse.

Comment: @Cheva: well, there are two issues then: is their method numerically accurate ? Is their method fast ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Ok, things in the real world that nedd to measure don't need extreme numerical precision. what I intend to find is the shortest distance between the segment and the ellipse, that is, I need to get the points p and p".

Comment: I have reworked my answer and brought it to its final form. I don't think you can make it much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

By a similarity transformation (translate the center to the origin and rotate the Eigenvectors to the coordinate axis), you can bring the ellipse to its canonical form

```
x²/a² + y²/b² = 1.
```

Simultaneously, the supporting line of the segment turns to equation

```
px + qy + r = 0.
```

Now, by using a parametric equation of the ellipse, we minimize

```
(p a cosΘ + q b sinΘ + r)²
```

and by cancelling the derivative,

```
-p a sinΘ + q b cosΘ = 0
```

or

```
tanΘ = q b / p a.
```

From the value of `Θ`, you get a point on the ellipse and check that it projects on the segment. If not, the shortest distance is to one of the segment endpoints. We minimize

```
(a cosΘ - x)² + (b sinΘ - y)²,
```

by

```
-a sinΘ (a cosΘ - x) + b cosΘ (b sinΘ - y) = 0.
```

Here it is advantageous to rationalize the expression by means of the Weierstrass substitution, and we get

```
- a 2t/(1+t²) (a (1-t²)/(1+t²) - x) + b (1-t²)/(1+t²) (b 2t/(1+t²) - y) = 0
```

or

```
- a 2t (a (1-t²) - x (1+t²)) + b (1-t²) (b 2t - y (1+t²)) = 0.
```

This is a quartic polynomial from which you can't escape, as there are as much as four solutions (of which you keep the shortest distance).